# jQuery. Prevent jump to top on append()

Tags: jquery, html

I have scrollable div

> ```
> <div id="scrollable" style="overflow-y: auto; height:200px;max-height:800px;width: 80px;">
> <div>
> <table id="chat_content"></table>
> </div>
> ```

And JS:

```
jQuery('#chat_content').append("<tr><td>Hi world</td></tr>");
```

But when i rich max. height and inserting, it lift me up to top of #scrollable

How to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#chat_content').scrollTop($('#chat_content')[0].scrollHeight);
```

It will scroll to the bottom of the chat div instantly. Run it after append().

Comment: It makes it scrolling down after adding, looks like crazy(